# std::set::insert, how bad can I hint?

Tags: c++

I'm doing lots and lots of inserts of `std::pair<int, int>` into a `std::set`, and it's taking longer than I'd like. When I wrote the code I figured I'd look at using the hint iterator form of insert later if it turned out to be a bottleneck; well, now it's profiled and it **is** a bottleneck. So I want to use the iterator hint.

However, I'm not always going to know a good position to insert my pairs. I typically insert them in batches (a batch in this case is on the order of 0.01% of the total input size, duplicates included) of increasing set-order, but when a batch is inserted, I do not know where the next one should start. How is the hint used? Does insert do something like a binary search from the suggested position? How bad would it be to use a bad hint, typically?

Comment: Longer than I'd like? I know `O(n)`, `O(log n)`, even `O(n^2)`... But `O(longer than I'd like)` is not in my text book

Comment: Well, things seldom take `O(log n)` seconds either... But doing ~200.000 inserts (with duplicates) takes about 4 seconds. It's a noticable delay for the user, and I'd like to shorten it if I can

Comment: If this is a bottleneck you could benchmark using `unordered_set`.  Boost or STL depending on your compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest just reading what the compiler reads: the header file for `#include <set>`. On my system (GNU libstdc++ 4.5.1) I can read the following self-explanatory text:

```
  /**
   *  @brief Attempts to insert an element into the %set.
   *  @param  position  An iterator that serves as a hint as to where the
   *                    element should be inserted.
   *  @param  x  Element to be inserted.
   *  @return  An iterator that points to the element with key of @a x (may
   *           or may not be the element passed in).
   *
   *  This function is not concerned about whether the insertion took place,
   *  and thus does not return a boolean like the single-argument insert()
   *  does.  Note that the first parameter is only a hint and can
   *  potentially improve the performance of the insertion process.  A bad
   *  hint would cause no gains in efficiency.
   *
   *  For more on @a hinting, see:
   *  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt07ch17.html
   *  
   *  Insertion requires logarithmic time (if the hint is not taken).
   */
  iterator
  insert(iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
  { return _M_t._M_insert_unique_(__position, __x); }
```

Takeaway:

1. **A bad hint would cause no gains in efficiency**
2. Insertion is `O(log n)`
3. You can read even more about [insertion hints in the GNU libstdc++ manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20100223102002/http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt07ch17.html).

Comment: Hm, so if the hint is not exactly right, it is probably disregarded altogether?

Comment: One has to read between the lines here. If the hint turns out to be incorrect, it probably turns around and immediately calls the non-hinted version - but that's not stated explicitly.

Comment: @carlpett:  Yes, probably.  Your C++ implementation could theoretically do something smarter (unlikely, but possible); if you specify your actual compiler and version, someone might be able to answer definitively.

Comment: The link is broken, is [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/associative.html#containers.associative.insert_hints) it?

Comment: @doug65536 Looks like it. The answer text had already been edited to point to the wayback machine :)

Answer (score 3):

If you check the file `bits/stl_tree.h` (in GNU libstdc++), you'll find that the `_M_insert_unique` member function with a hint argument looks one node to the left of the hint, then one node to the right, then defaults to calling the ordinary insert routine.

It calls `key_compare` at least once (if the set is not empty) and at most three times. Going from one node to the next or previous is a matter of following a pointer since (IIRC) `std::set` and friends are [threaded trees](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).

So, how bad a bad hint is depends on the comparison routine, and on whether your `std::set`'s allocator packs nodes close in memory.

Answer (score 0):

A hint is good if it is the *right* hint - the position to use for an insert. Works if you insert objects sequentially, for example.

If the hint is not correct, it has no effect and you get a non-hinted insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the set all at once before you use it, you can use a vector instead and sort it before you use it. You can use the `binary_search`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, and `equal_range` algorithms on a sorted vector for fast lookups. You can also use `merge` or `inplace_merge` to combine sorted vectors, and `set_difference`, `set_intersection`, and `set_union` to do other common set operations.